# What does this yum package version mean?

Tags: rhel, yum, dnf

On Rocky Linux:

```
$ sudo yum list squid
Available Packages
squid.x86_64   7:4.15-3.module+el8.6.0+842+aea5c28d
```

What does the `7:` and the `.module ...` part of the version string mean? I can see the installed package is version 4.15, and I know the `-3` is the build (although that might not be the right terminology). Any reference to yum/dnf version syntax docs also appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use either `yum info` or `dnf info` as appropriate and the full breakdown is shown:

```
$ dnf info squid
...
Name         : squid
Epoch        : 7
Version      : 4.15
Release      : 3.module_el8.6.0+2741+01592ae8
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 3.6 M
Source       : squid-4.15-3.module_el8.6.0+2741+01592ae8.src.rpm
Repository   : appstream
```

a somewhat simpler example would be:

```
dnf info xfsprogs.x86_64
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:52 ago on Mon 23 May 2022 12:35:10 BST.
Installed Packages
Name         : xfsprogs
Version      : 5.0.0
Release      : 10.el8
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 4.9 M
Source       : xfsprogs-5.0.0-10.el8.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
```

Note that the "epoch" has disappeared and the release string is simpler.  You just picked on a particularly complex release string in your question.

Following the link that "lost" found, the epoch explanation is as follows:

The epoch is a more important version number than the major number.  Normally it should be 0, in which case it is not reported, but may be any integer.  Note that a version of 2.0-0 will never update a version of 1:1.9-9 because the epoch of "1:" is greater than the default assumed epoch of "0:".  In the case of squid above, only epochs equal to or greater than 7 will ever be considered.

Comment: Thanks. I found the docs for [epoch](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#epoch) which was helpful, any ideas /why/ the release would be so complicated?? What does that signify/what are the consequences? Given the same docs suggest it should just be a number.

Comment: I'm currently trying to nail it down hard enough to be part of the answer.  Modules are packages that provide a logical group.  However in my example `squid` is in stream 4 (use `$ dnf module list --all squid`) but the info shows 3.module.

Comment: The best explanation of the module versioning I've found is [fedoraproject.org](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/modularity/core-concepts/module-dependency-resolution/) but it doesn't clarify why squid has "el8.6.0+2741+01592ae8" as the stream name.